# batch file to find repeated mac addresses in a text document

Tags: batch-file, text

I'm struggling.. I have a text file that contains lots of mac addresses - what I want to do is find any duplicate mac addresses that appear.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Kind Regards Craig.

Comment: is there anything else in the file besides the mac addresses, or is it just one mac address per line? Can you show a snippet of the file? Also, what operating system do you need to do this on? Is a scripting language solution acceptable?

Comment: Hi Batch would be best.. the lines are as follows 000000000944   000000000944      0   <client-mac>00:11:50:A0:BE:26</client-mac>
00000000158F   00000000158F      0   <client-mac>00:1E:2A:EA:69:4E</client-mac>
000000001AE6   000000001AE6      0   <client-mac>00:26:5E:17:E4:B7</client-mac>
00000000271B   00000000271B      0   <client-mac>00:1F:33:B5:66:D4</client-mac>
00000000321D   00000000321D      0   <client-mac>00:26:5E:17:E4:B7</client-mac>

Comment: so what im trying to do is if the mac addresses repeat I could put them in another text doc or highlight the duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a line looks like this:

```
000000000944 000000000944 0 <client-mac>00:11:50:A0:BE:26</client-mac>
```

this should do:

```
@echo off
copy nul out.txt >nul
for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i in (file.txt) do (
 find "%%i" out.txt>nul && (
  echo doublette: %%i>>out.txt 
 ) || (
  echo unique: %%i>>out.txt
 )
)
```

`&&` means: "if errorlevel = 0 then do..."

`||` means: "if errorlevel is not 0 then do..."

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if defined macAddress[%%a] (
      echo Duplicated mac address: %%a
   ) else (
      set macAddress[%%a]=true
   )
)) > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in PowerShell without too much difficulty:

```
get-content "test.dat" | select-string '((?:[0-9A-F]{2}:){5}[0-9A-F]{2})' | foreach-object {
  $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
} | sort-object -unique | out-file "results.txt"
```